# permission_handler not asking for location

Tags: flutter, permissions, location

I'm using the permission_handler package for flutter. I'm successfully asking for the permissions on the camera, camera roll and the microphone.
But there is nothing popping up that asks me for the location.

I'm using this snippet to ask for the permission in my onboarding screen:

```
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
            Permission.location,
            Permission.storage,
            Permission.camera,
            Permission.photos,
            Permission.microphone,
          ].request().whenComplete(() {
            print('Permission.location.status');
            print(Permission.location.status);
            ///load main
            _onIntroEnd(context);
          });
```

This is the post_install in my podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
      # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
      #
      # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
      # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
      #
      #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1'
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>WunderKlub</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>

    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>

    <!-- Permission options for the `camera` group -->
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>WunderKlub macht nur Spass mit Kamera.</string>

    <!-- Permission options for the `microphone` group -->
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Das Mikro nutzt WunderKlub gar nicht, es muss aber trotzdem abgefragt werden.</string>

    <!-- Permission options for the `photos` group -->
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>WunderKlub möchte deine Fotos speichern können.</string>

    <!-- Permission options for the `location` group -->
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need location when in use</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always and when in use!</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Older devices need location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can I have location always?</string>
    

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Does the app already have permissions?

Check "Settings -> Privacy -> <app_name>" on iOS,

Answer (score 0):

This was very strange, in the end I restarted my Mac and my IPhone and it worked. Sometimes it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You've commented on the code for notification. Please uncomment it, that will do the job

```
   ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
   # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
```

- Also if your [androidSdkInt] <= 33 (Android Version <= 12) the
  location permission is auto-granted